# How to save each row of a database as a seperate data block file in a directory using perl?

Tags: database, arrays, perl, hash

Right now, I have a database with around 20 columns and 70 rows. I want to iterate through each row and save each row as a separate data block, with the file name being generated by the first three columns. I already have SQL code selecting the specific columns I want and ordering it according to the parameters I want. The directory I want the files is in `c:/database/first_past`.

In my code, `$ds` is a variable that is an array of hashes, i.e. my current database. I have two for loops that iterate through the database and get down to the row, but I am unsure about the line to insert to save the row as its own separate file in the directory mentioned above with the specific title parameters.

Is this possible in Perl? Here is a portion of the code I am currently using:

```
for my $rec (@{$ds->{DATA}}) {
    for my $role (keys %{$rec} } {
        #here is the save file line? ("$role=$rec->{$role}"
    }
}
```

`$ds` is an array of hashes and the `DATA` field is all the data for one row.

Comment: What kind of database? PostgreSQL? MySQL? MongoDB?

Comment: Oops, sorry, I never included that. Oracle Database.

Comment: Why don't you show us the code so we can help you? It sure is possible. Also show what the file is supposed to look like.

Comment: I posted the code. The whole file is just suppose to look like a block of code. Simply the text of each row separated by a comma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use DBI qw( );

my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $passwd, {
   RaiseError       => 1,
   PrintError       => 0,
   PrintWarn        => 1,
   AutoCommit       => 1,
   FetchHashKeyName => 'NAME_lc',
});

my $sth = $dbh->prepare('
    SELECT *
      FROM Table
     ORDER BY ...
');

$sth->execute();
while (my $row = $sth->fetch()) {
    my $fn = join('-', @{$row}[0,1,2]);
    my $qfn = "c:\\database\\first_past\\" . $fn;
    open(my $fh, '>', $qfn) or die $!;
    print($fh ...);
}
```

[DBI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI), [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html), [`print`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html)

---

For your follow up question:

```
$sth->execute();
while (my $row = $sth->fetch()) {
    my $fn = join('-', @{$row}[0,1,2]);
    my $qfn = "c:\\database\\first_past\\" . $fn;
    open(my $fh, '>>', $qfn) or die $!;
    print($fh ...);
}
```

or

```
my $last_fn;
my $fh;
$sth->execute();
while (my $row = $sth->fetch()) {
    my $fn = join('-', @{$row}[0,1,2]);
    if (!defined($last_fn) || $last_fn ne $fn) {
        $last_fn = $fn;
        my $qfn = "c:\\database\\first_past\\" . $fn;
        open($fh, '>', $qfn) or die $!;
    }

    print($fh ...);
}
```

Comment: `fetchrow_hashref` can be used instead of `fetch` if you want to access the fields by name instead of by position.

Comment: I was gonna suggest [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.21/lib/Text/CSV.pm) but this is of course the quickest way.

Comment: @simbabque, You mean use some other tool to execute the query and dump the result to a CSV file, then have the script read through the CSV? Well, I could see that being done for performance reasons, but we're talking about 70 rows.

Comment: What is the database were 70,000 rows? Which way would be the fastest then?

Comment: Try it and find out. I've never done any such benchmarking. Mind you, I suspect the time taken to create a file for each record is probably going eclipse any differences.

Comment: Would you know a way to modify this if instead, I wanted a different data block only when the first three columns changed. So instead of a new data block every row, I would want a new data block after the one of the first three columns change.

Comment: Simplest change: `>` to `>>`. But you could also move the handle to outside the loop, and save the first there columns in variables outside of loop so that you can check if there's been a change. Code added to bottom of answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. That makes a lot of sense now.